# Possible to connect multiple Macs via Thunderbolt Networking (IP over Thunderbolt)?

Tags: network, thunderbolt

Looking to connect 4 Macs to a central Mac Mini that is running as a server (with a few Thunderbolt RAID arrays connected it as data sources).

Network is currently gigabit ethernet, but would like to speed up data transfers.  [10G Thunderbolt Ethernet Adapters](https://www.akitio.com/adapters/thunder2-10g-network-adapter) are still relatively expensive ($300-500) - so I'm wondering if its possible to connect multiple Macs via IP over Thunderbolt?

Apple [supports](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25217?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) a direct connection between two computers via IP, but is it possible to connect multiple either via daisy chaining them or via some sort of a Thunderbolt hub or switch (if one exists)?

If so, this would make for a relatively inexpensive way to build a 10G LAN network with (mostly) existing hardware and a few [Optical Thunderbolt Cables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KTIY5Y0)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes you can do this. You would need a Mac with multiple Thunderbolt ports like a 2013 MacPro with its 6 Thunderbolt ports. Not sure if daisy chaining multiple Macs together will give you the desired effect.

This [link](https://macperformanceguide.com/ThunderboltNetworking-SettingUp.html) seems to think that it will work but says nothing about daisy chaining only plugging a bunch of Macs into one Mac with a lot of ports.

So it *seems* that it is safe to plug a bunch of Macs together VIA thunderbolt which opens the door to you experimenting with various topologies to find one that does what you want.